# Send SQL Report in E mail attachment using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to send report from sql reportserver 2008 as e mail attachment using ASP.NET and C#, 
Till now I learned how to [Get report as PDF](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/10/29/exporting-a-sql-server-reporting-services-2005-report-directly-to-pdf-or-excel.aspx) in my code ,
Now I wanna combine line of codes like

```
byte[] bytes = rview.ServerReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Attachment reportAttachment = new Attachment(Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length),"ado"); //Here I go wrong
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I getting this wrong (I know little about SSRS) but I think you should

1. Save the file to the file system

   ```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\temp.pdf", bytes);
   ```
2. Send the file by email

   ```
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.From        = "Me";
   mail.To          = "You";
   mail.Subject     = "Subject";
   mail.Body        = "Body";
   mail.BodyFormat  = MailFormat.Html;
   mail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment("c:\temp\temp.pdf"));

   try
   {
      SmtpMail.Send(mail); 
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      Response.Write("Ouch! " + ex.Message);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks System.IO works like charm, Only one little remark, firs argument is String address of file and second is byte[].
Any way now I have an idea to make web service for doing this job,
Will it be so hard and different than making just sample Web page

Answer (score 15):

Instead of saving the pdf to the file system first, you could try to use the byte[] returned from the report server and attach this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes); 
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "temp.pdf"));
```

For a quick fudge on one of my reports I did the following:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData("http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx? *** report name *** &rs%3aFormat=PDF");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "temp.pdf"));
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Attaching without saving the file to the file system is a much more elegant solution, in my opinion. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This works nicely although I had to use System.Net.Mail rather so that I could create the Attachment from a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use SSRS Subscriptions. It has email functionality built-in.

Prerequisites:

- You have your report set up.
- You have your SSRS report Server configured to send emails.
- Your SSRS server is 2010 or later. I'm not sure if 2008 and before support subscriptions.

[Microsoft's documentation from the UI standpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307.aspx#bkmk_create_email_subscription)

Code:

```
var service = new ReportingService2010();
service.Url = reportServiceURL;
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

var reportPath = "your/report/location";

string report = $"{reportPath}YourReportName.rdl";
string fileName = $"Your Custom Report";

//If your report requires input parameters, specify them in an array.
ParameterValue[] reportParameters = new ParameterValue[1];

reportParameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
reportParameters[0].Name = "ID";
reportParameters[0].Value = ID.ToString();

ParameterValue[] extensionParams = new ParameterValue[11];//Adjust this if you omit parameters.

extensionParams[0] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[0].Name = "TO";
extensionParams[0].Value = "BOB@company.com;Sharon@company.com;Bill.Gates@microsoft.com;"

//CC, can be omitted.
extensionParams[1] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[1].Name = "CC";
extensionParams[1].Value = "Doug@company.com;Hillary@company.com;"

//BCC, can be omitted.
extensionParams[2] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[2].Name = "BCC";
extensionParams[2].Value = "Doug@company.com;Hillary@company.com;"

//Reply to, where replies should go.
extensionParams[3] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[3].Name = "ReplyTo";
extensionParams[3].Value = "YourMonitoredMailbox@company.com"

//Include report as an attachment, this should be TRUE.
extensionParams[4] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[4].Name = "IncludeReport";
extensionParams[4].Value = "True"

//What you want the attached file to render as. You have some options.
extensionParams[5] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[5].Name = "RenderFormat";
extensionParams[5].Value = "PDF"; //pdf
//extensionParams[5].Value = "WORD"; //doc, word 2003 - 2007
//extensionParams[5].Value = "WORDOPENXML"; //docx, word 2010 - 2013+
//extensionParams[5].Value = "EXCEL"; //xls, excel 2003 - 2007
//extensionParams[5].Value = "EXCELOPENXML"; //xlsx, excel 2010 - 2013+
//extensionParams[5].Value = "IMAGE"; //TIFF file
//extensionParams[5].Value = "CSV"; //CSV file
//extensionParams[5].Value = "XML"; //XML file

//Optional, set the priority of the message.
extensionParams[6] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[6].Name = "Priority";
extensionParams[6].Value = "High";
//extensionParams[6].Value = "Normal";
//extensionParams[6].Value = "Low";

//Subject Line
extensionParams[7] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[7].Name = "Subject";
extensionParams[7].Value = "Your lovely report";

//Comment, I believe this is the "body" of the email.
extensionParams[8] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[8].Name = "Comment";
extensionParams[8].Value = "Hi there, <br/><br/>I have your report. Thanks for automating me out of the job, you programmer you!";

//Include a hyperlink to run the report in the email body?  Can be omitted.
extensionParams[9] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[9].Name = "IncludeLink";
extensionParams[9].Value = "False";

//If you want to send it "on behalf of" someone, use this. Can be omitted.
extensionParams[10] = new ParameterValue();
extensionParams[10].Name = "SendEmailToUserAlias";
extensionParams[10].Value = "Bob.McCarthy@company.com";

ExtensionSettings extSettings = new ExtensionSettings();
extSettings.ParameterValues = extensionParams;
extSettings.Extension = "Report Server Email";

//FYI date must be in ISO 8601 format. This sets it to one minute from now, and will only run once.
string matchData = $"<ScheduleDefinition><StartDateTime>{DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("s")}</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>";

reportingService.CreateSubscription(reportName, extSettings, fileName, "TimedSubscription", matchData, reportParameters);
```